# Return specific value from a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out a way to return the value from a specific position inside a 2D array in JAVA. I've been searching for hours. I might be tired, or using the wrong terms but I can't find anything useful so far...

So for example I have a variable "a" and I want it to receive the value that is contained at a specific array position.

So for example, I want the value contained at the position :

```
array[1][1]
```

To be saved into the variable "a". Any way to do this? Btw it's a 9x9 array so it contains 81 different value but I only need 1 specific value out of the array at a time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what type of array is this? assuming int array... `int a = array[1][1]` if you have `a` already declared just do..  `a = array[1][1]`

Comment: When I do this, the variable a always gets the value 0... but yes it is an INT array

Comment: Would you like to loop through every element in the array?... You're question is confusing and the added comment makes me more confused..

Comment: @itSp4x If it's `0` then that's because that's what the value is. Can you show what you're trying to do?

Comment: @itSp4x how is the array initialized? Please post your code.

Comment: Alright I'll give a bit more context, yes I'll be looping through every element in order to compare it to another element. If it's already present then it won't allow to place this new value inside the array. I already know how to do everything else I really just need the right syntax to give "a" the value contained at the specific coordinate.

Comment: @itSp4x The syntax is `a = array[1][1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just assign the value from the array as desired:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
        int a = arr[1][1];
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

// outputs : 5
```

Note that if a value hasn't been put in an array position then it will be in the uninitialized state. For an int this is 0.

```
int[][] arr = new int[9][9];
// all values in arr will be 0
```

Comment: Thanks this does exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the "Object type" you would assign using `Object a = array[1][1];` and you can be more specific, as in `int a = array[1][1];`. GL